# Android Location Interval change

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am trying to make my location algorythm smarter by changing the minimum interval of location update depending on the current speed of the user. There is the problem with the following code, no mather of the speed i constantly get updates every 8 seconds. I would appriciate any help. 
Here is the main part of the code:

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Location lastLocation = getLastLocation();

        if(lastLocation != null){

            double speed=location.distanceTo(lastLocation)/((getMilSecFromDate(getCurrentDateTime())-lastLocation.getTime())/1000);
            speedTmp = speed;

            if(!isLocEqual(location,lastLocation)){
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, speed+"   "+"Location:  " + "Time:  " + getCurrentDateTime() + "   Latitude:  " + location.getLatitude() + "  Longitude:  "
                        + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                timeMoved=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                //if battery is under 20%, service is shutted down
                if(batPercent<20){
                    onDestroy();
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Battery under 20%, charge", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(speed<=10&&speed>2){
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Hodanje - speed " +speed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MIN_TIME=1000*60;
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, locationListener);
                    Log.i("gpsSetvice", "speed<10");
                }
                else if(speed>10 && speed<60){
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Izmedju 10 i 60 - speed " +speed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MIN_TIME=1000*30;
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, locationListener);
                    Log.i("gpsSetvice", "speed>10 && speed<60");
                }
                else if(speed>=60 && speed<100){
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "izmedju 60 i 100 " +speed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MIN_TIME=1000*20;
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, locationListener);
                    Log.i("gpsSetvice", "speed>=60 && speed<100");
                }
                else if(speed>=100){
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Preko 100 - speed " +speed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MIN_TIME=1000*2*60;
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, locationListener);
                    Log.i("gpsSetvice", "speed>=MILE");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to start and stop the location manager for changes to take effect.

Comment: how do you mean to stop the location manager? I already used locationManager.removeUpdates();

Comment: my bad didn't see that.

Comment: What I don't see is 8000 mili seconds in your code.  To get 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is, that you call removeUpdates and requestLocationUpdates every time when onLocationChanged is called. When you call `requestLocationUpdates`, GPS starts working immediately and tries to fix your location as soon as possible.

**When the location is fixed, next fix will be performed after the delay you specified, but you don't allow that, because you restart the process by calling removeUpdates and requestLocationUpdates every time.** I think that's why you always get GPS fix after a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I removed the removeUpadates() statement and i still get the same result as before.

Comment: I think the problem is rather requestLocationUpdates, because it starts GPS  fixing immediately when called, if I am correct.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get speed from your GPS location as bellow:

```
int updateCount=0;
float totalSpeedSum=0.0f;
float avgSpeed=0.0f;
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Location lastLocation = getLastLocation();

    // speed in m/sec
    float curSpeed=location.getSpeed();
    updateCount++;
    totalSpeedSum=totalSpeedSum+curSpeed;
    avgSpeed=totalSpeedSum/updateCount;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, i know for that function, but i need average speed.

Comment: Add your speed on every location updates and count every location updates then use formula avg. speed=(total speed sum)/count. See edited answer.